# finding the radius of a cylinder based on camera position

Tags: linear-algebra, computer-science, 3d, computer-vision

Not entirely sure this is the right forum, but I'll give it a go.

I have a cylinder that is projected onto a 2d plane (3d world with a virtual camera).

What I want to figure out is, given a point on the 2d viewing plane, how large does the cylinder need to be in order for it's "edge" to align with said point

[image]

Basically from that image:
given the red point how much larger does the cylinder have to be? (the blue line)

Comment: What do you mean by "it's edge", do you mean the "surface" of the cylinder, or do you mean the "upper circular edge" ?

Comment: I think I mean the surface

Answer (score 3):

If you mean the bottom of the cylinder reaching the red point, you need 'Pythagoras Theorem'.

Just ignore the height of the cylinder.
You can  then work out its required radius (AB), in the 2D plane like this
[image]

---

Alternatively, if you mean that the cylinder should be enlarged to reach the dotted blue line, then it should be $4$ times the radius, going from a radius of $5$ to $20$, so the radius should be increased by $15$ units (green line)

[image]

Comment: I think same thing goes for the top of the cylinder. just throw a line from the camera towards the point(raycast) and see where that intersects the plane p0 (0,<cylinder height>,0) and n (0,1,0). Then after ignoring the Y value of the intersection you can rightfully use pythagoras to get the upper radius